# How to split a List into View in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, chart.js

I am using ChartJS to draw a chart. Only separated values can be processed on the accepted values lables and data. But in my case, the text is monolithic. In general, I cannot format the text in any way when passing List to View.

View

```
<script>
function chart1() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
    window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: [@foreach (var m in Model) { @m.NameArea}],
            datasets: [{
                    label: 'Районы',
                data: [@foreach (var m in Model) { @m.AreaParameter}],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
};</script>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string connString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        List<Area> currentArea = new List<Area>();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT NameArea, AreaParameter FROM FileTable", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                List<Area> dictList = new List<Area>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    currentArea.Add(new Area()
                    {
                        //Id = Int32.Parse(reader["id"].ToString()),
                        NameArea = reader["NameArea"].ToString(),
                        AreaParameter = Int32.Parse(reader["AreaParameter"].ToString())
                    });
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand comDelete = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM FileTable", conn);
        comDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        return View(currentArea);
    }
}
```

As a result, the script gets the list

```
labels: [OneTwoThreeFour]
```

I would like to see

```
labels: ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
```

I really need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try formatting your output. Something like below should work.

```
labels: @String.Join(",", Model.Select(x => $"'{x.NameArea}'"))
```

So basically what this is doing is instead of a foreach we are selecting just the name area from all of the models in your list. That Select is also adding single quotes around your NameArea using String Interpolation. From there we are doing a join to comma delimit the list.

Hopefully this works for you.

Comment: in general I did almost the same, only much worse)

`labels: [@foreach (var m in Model) {@Html.Raw("'"+String.Join("', '", m.NameArea)+"', ")}]`

but thanks anyway, it makes me optimize the code.

Comment: No problem. If it works please mark it as the answer. Have a good day.